# Videos don't display on mobile

Tags: html

For some reason my videos work good on PC and exactly how i want, but, on mobile, never mind if it's android or IOS, videos don't show. Just a blank space in box where video should be.

```html
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1">
  <video playsinline autoplay loop muted class="embed-responsive-item">
    <source src="static/video/legs/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<video width="800" height="800" style="margin-top: 150px; box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 3px #635a5a;border-radius: 8px;" controls="">
    <source src="assets/images/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This is responsive and works over all the devices

Comment: It is not responsive. It has fixed width of 800 x 800

Comment: this code is put after "mbed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1" div.
so if above class is responsive this video code will automatically responsive.

Comment: Okay, i can try this, but except this css element, what is different? Why this should work and my code don't?